# Stopping time and expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ denote a martingale with respect to some filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$, and let $\tau$ denote a stopping time with $P(\tau<\infty)=1$. Assume that there exists an $M$ such that $|X_n|1_{(n\leq \tau)}\leq M$, in other words that $(X_n)$ is bounded up til time $\tau$.

Now, I want to show that $E(|X_{\tau}|)<\infty$. But since $|X_n|1_{(n\leq \tau)}\leq M$, wouldn't we have that $|X_{\tau}|\leq M$? Then the result should be obvious.

Furthermore, I am to show that $E(X_{\tau})=E(X_0)$. My idea is as follows: I show that $E(X_{\tau\wedge n})\to E(X_\tau)$ for $n\to\infty$ - simply by writing $X_{n\wedge \tau}=X_{\tau}1_{\tau\leq n}+X_n1_{n<\tau}$, and letting $n$ go to infinity. Then I can just apply a result which states that, if $X$ is a martingale and $T$ is a stopping time, then $X^T$ is a martingale, so that in particular, $E(X_{T\wedge n})=E(X_0)$ for all $n$.

Are these assessments correct? Should I perhaps be more clear?